# How do I prevent a Grails domain from being updated or deleted?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Once the domain is created and saved, I want to enforce that it doesn't get updated or deleted.  What's the simplest and most effective way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to add two methods, `beforeUpdate` and `beforeDelete`, to your Grails domain that both return `false`.  The available GORM event methods are described in the documentation [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping).

```
class Example {
    def beforeUpdate() {
        return false;
    }
    def beforeDelete() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just throw some kind of OperationNotAllowedException in `beforeUpdate` & `beforeDelete`